# How to make JavaScript indent local in Emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation

I use builtin javascript mode and when I call `(setq js-indent-level 2)` all files have indent set to 2 not only the current file. Is it possible to make that indent local to just current buffer file?

Comment: Besides `setq-local` there's a way to have it set for a file each time you visit that file: [File variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables)

Comment: @Biffen, good point, though I usually find [directory variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `setq-local`:

```lisp
(setq-local js-indent-level 2)
```

[From the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html):

> This macro creates a buffer-local binding in the current buffer for *variable*, and gives it the buffer-local value *value*. It is equivalent to calling `make-local-variable` followed by `setq`. *variable* should be an unquoted symbol.